# How to set up distributed systems with a .net core 3.1 backend

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, messagebroker, event-bus, nats.io

My department is coming from a .**NET 4.8 wcf/wpf client/server** architecture world. But times change and there a new requirements on connecting **.NET** back-ends to web applications, mobile apps and (also) desktop applications. We have experience on how to transfer messages from back-end to clients, as we implemented our own net. **TCP** message broker.

**And here comes the first main topic of my question:**

*#1 Is the usage of a google **protobuf/amqp** event broker the right way to connect micro-services with all kind of clients (web, mobile, desktop), as well as with other back-end components?*

My current investigation led me to 3 products:

- [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) with its amqp
- [NATS/STAN](https://github.com/nats-io/nats-server) with a google protobuf message protocol including event storage in MySQL/Postegres
- [Eventstore](https://www.eventstore.com/) with google protobuf message protocol including event storave in an own database system

**Which leads me to my second question:**

*#2 What experience did you make with any of these products? Any pros, cons or snares?*

We don't need any clustered systems or highly scalable solutions, as every customer has its own encapsulated system with < 40 clients. But we want a reliable message/event transmission (which should be  achieved by any of the 3 mentioned brokers).

BR Christian

Comment: You forgot SignalR which works in .NET Old and .NET Core (although with different implementations). Mobiles are a completely different story, as almost *everyone* uses the notification services provided by one platform or another. Even web apps use platform notifications for those annoying web site notifications. This question is far too broad to answer

Comment: The 3 products are very different too and in fact, one could use *all* of them in the same project. One is a "simple" message broker, the second a complex CNCF messaging system with some overlap with RabbitMQ while the third is an implementation of something completely unrelated - a database for DDD-style events.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your feedback. We did not consider SignalR, as we need reliable message delivery. As far as I know, SignalR does not guarantee message delivery.